# Backend transactions with REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, transactions

I have a question on REST API and how to create some back-end transactions in our application. 
We have an accounting application, and so for every transaction created there is a ledger entry. (though client - javascript is unaware of such entries)

For instance, in REST we create a transaction through -

```
POST /transactions/
```

(or)

```
POST /accounts/1223/transactions/
```

Now, when I deal with this in RestController, 
I want to do the following -

- Create the Transaction based on POST.
- Create a ledger entry in the back-end. (Client - javascript should be unaware)
- Update the balance entry on the account. (Client - javascript should be unaware)

In the TransactionService in spring java app (this should be immaterial though, as my question is focused on REST API semantics),

```
@Transactional
public void saveTransaction(Transaction t) {
    transactionRepo.save(t);
    Ledger l = new Ledger(<particulars>)();
    ledgerRepo.save(l);
    Balance b = balanceService.get(<partiulars>);
    balanceRepo.update(b);
}
```

1. I am confused with the REST API approach as they only update the
       resource. Doesn't updating a resource change other underlying particulars in the application?
2. Reading about REST confuses on how transactions atomicity is
   tackled. What is the solution for such activities in REST?
3. I cannot do these multi-saves from the client (javascript) using multi-phase approach (saving transaction first, then with transaction id creating ledger etc) as the client application should be unaware of such back-end service-related actions.

Could someone explain clearly in this particular scenario how to approach?

Many applications are finance and accounting related, but I just don't get why REST won't fit for such practical scenario. Might be my understanding is different.

Answer (score 0):

> when I deal with this in RestController, I want to do the following -
>
> - Create the Transaction based on POST.
> - Create a ledger entry in the back-end. (Client - javascript should be unaware)
> - Update the balance entry on the account. (Client - javascript should be unaware)

That all seems pretty reasonable.

> I am confused with the REST API approach as they only update the resource.

So my diagnosis is that you are a victim of [semantic diffusion](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/SemanticDiffusion.html); how much did the meaning of REST change before you learned it?

Your best starting point may be [Jim Webber's 2011 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=4m3s)

> You have to learn how to use HTTP to trigger business activity as a side effect of moving documents around the network.

HTTP tells you what the semantics of the requests are -- that's what REST calls the "uniform interface" -- but it doesn't say anything about the side effects.  The fact that, in your domain, you respond to a POST request by updating ledgers and balances is *fine*.

If it helps: it's exactly the same way a web site works.  You fill in a form and submit it, and some web page (resource) changes as a result, *but also* a bunch of interesting things happen on the back end.